# What is the wrong with this code in javascript else if conditional?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

when I run this code it gives me always the same result "your balance is $ 250.00."
I changed the variables to get different answers but I think there is something wrong I don't know.
Attached is a flow chart describes what are the code for and the process.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac4PH.jpg)

```
enter code here

**// change the values of `balance`, `checkBalance`, and `isActive` to test 
your code
var balance = 250;
var checkBalance = false;
var isActive = true;
// your code goes here
if (checkBalance = false){
    console.log("thank you! Have a nice day.");
}
else if (isActive = true && balance > 0){
    console.log("your balance is $ " + balance.toFixed(2) + ".");
}
else if (isActive = false){
    console.log("Your account is no longer active.");
}
else if (balance = 0){
    console.log("Your account is empty.");
}
else if (balance < 0) {
    console.log("Your account is negative. Please, contact bank.");
}**
```

Comment: `if (checkBalance = false){` condition will always be true.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: or never be true, rather

Comment: @Ryan oh yes, sorry got confused. Thanks for correcting :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use comparisons ( `===` or `==`) in the statements, not assignments `=`. With `boolean` types you can emit the `===` part and use the value with or without `!`. Every value is going to be cast into the `boolean` type, so `checkBalance === true` is equivalent to just `checkBalance` and `checkBalance === false` is equivalent to just `!checkBalance`.

```js
var balance = 250;
var checkBalance = false;
var isActive = true;

if (!checkBalance){
    console.log("thank you! Have a nice day.");
}
else if (isActive && balance > 0){
    console.log("your balance is $ " + balance.toFixed(2) + ".");
}
else if (!isActive){
    console.log("Your account is no longer active.");
}
else if (balance === 0){
    console.log("Your account is empty.");
}
else if (balance < 0) {
    console.log("Your account is negative. Please, contact bank.");
}
```